# How to change the ectension .php to for example .123 on lighttpd

Tags: php, lighttpd

I want php to use another extension like .123 instead of .php. When I add fastcgi.map-extensions    = ( ".123" => ".php" ) I get an access denied when I try to open the page .123

I also get a access denied when I change  fastcgi.server += ( ".php" => to fastcgi.server += ( ".123" => on the config below when I try to open the page.

```
 fastcgi.server += ( ".php" =>
         ((
                 "socket" => "/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock",
                 "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
         ))
 )
```

Do I maybe have to add/change something  more?

Comment: If you use `fastcgi.map-extensions` then you should leave `fastcgi.server += ( ".php" => ...)` as-is.  Make sure that your fastcgi backend is up and running, and that the path to the php-fpm socket is correct (and matches the version you have running on your system).

Comment: Yes I know. It is one or the other. And something changes normally it wants to download the file and if I add fastcgi.map-extensions = (".123" => ".php") I get an Access denied. Do I have to add the mime type too for .123? Only I can't find the list of mime types anywhere.

Comment: Try renaming your .123 to .php and test that.  It sounds like your backend is broken.  Have you checked the lighttpd error.log for clues?

Comment: Thanks gstrauss. Following your reaction, I discovered that in /etc/php/7.3/fmp/pool.d/www.conf you have to enable security.limit_extensions = .cgi. It works now perfect

Comment: May not edit anymore. But of course it must be security.limit_extensions = .123